# Solution of domain includes $x=0$; why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

With a student, I found this simple radicand, for which I have to find the domain: $\sqrt{x^3-3x^2}$.

Of course, the first thing we did was to simplify it a bit, in order to have
$\sqrt{x^2(x-3)}$.

So, the study of the sign of the second equation is very simple, for we know that every radical must be $\geq 0$, so $x-3 \geq 0 \implies x \geq 3$.

For the second one, instead, I have some problems: if we know that any $x^2 \ge 0$, then I would say that  $x^2 \geq 0~\text{ for any $x$ belonging to $\mathbb{R}$}$.

So, I personally do not understand why our textbook lists even $x=0$ as its solution. And it baffles me that the solution is right (for IT IS), but I seriously cannot explain why anymore.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: If $x=0$ then the sign of $(x-3)$ doesn't matter. The sign can be even negative.

Comment: Of course, I tried to put in on WolphramAlpha as well and it correctly says that its domain is x=0 OR x>=3

I do not still where this x=0 comes from, if sqrt(x^2)>=0 is always verified

Comment: Perhaps what you are confusing yourself with is thinking that $\sqrt{x^2(x-3)}$ and $\sqrt{x^2}\cdot \sqrt{x-3}$ are equivalent expressions.  You think you can check each of these two radicals separately...  But they aren't the same expression.  In the first case, plugging in $x=0$ we have it simplifies to $\sqrt{0}$ which is of course allowed and equals zero.  In the second case, plugging in $x=0$ we have $\sqrt{0}\cdot \sqrt{-3}$ which when restricting yourself to the real squareroot only and ignoring complex numbers is undefined.  Of course, second expression isn't same so doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6):

Let try in this way, separating the given inequality in two cases, the strict inequality and the equality, we have:

> $$x^3-3x^2 \ge 0 \quad \iff\quad  x^2(x-3) > 0 \quad \lor \quad x^2(x-3) = 0$$

and

$$\begin{cases}x^2(x-3) > 0 \iff x>3\\\\x^2(x-3) = 0 \iff x=0 \quad \lor \quad x=3\end{cases}$$

that is $x\in\{0\}\cup[3,\infty)$.

Comment: This is the best way to express it, even if it splits the problem into two sub-problems. Not a big hassle, of course, but if I try to solve it as
x^2(x-3) >=0 and then split the two things, I would find that
x^2 >=0 for any x in R (so it should be very managable)
x >=3

So, the question is: where do I get the solution "x=0" in the method I wrote above?

Comment: @Andopolo In the solution you write above, the solutions for which the radical is equal to zero are solutions, then the condition $x^2\ge 0$ lead to $x=0$ as a solution.

Comment: @Andopolo In any case the key fact is that by definition $a\ge b \equiv a>b\: \lor \: a=b$.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that if you multiply any number by $0$, the result is $0$ (whether the number is nonnegative or not). The equation
$$x^2=0$$
Only holds when $x=0$, so it is also a solution, since the domain of
$$y=\sqrt{x}$$
Is $x\in[0,\infty)$. It's just a special case that you have to check.

Comment: When we look for a domain on a singular square root, however, should not we check if that equation is >=0? So, in this case, should not we check if x^2>=0?

Comment: @Andopolo What do you mean? $x^2$ is always $\ge 0$, just we have to check if **Equality occurs**

Comment: That is the main point of my incomprehension. If x^2  is always ≥0, why is 0 listed as a solution of the domain (for it is)?

Comment: @Andopolo Because $0\cdot -3=0$ and $\sqrt{0}=0\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

The reason that $x=0$ is in the solution set is because when you plug in $0$ into the function, it evaluates to zero, which is allowed in square roots, as you know. However, if you were to move slightly away from zero, say $x=0.1$, then the function would become undefined. So the solution set ends up being: $x\in {0} \cup [3, \infty)$.