# What is the standard way to represent combining inequalities.

Tags: notation

I'm writing up a simple review math lesson and I came across a simple question I couldn't find the answer for.

If I had something like

$x>2$ or $x=2$

this could combine to

$x \ge 2$

But how would we write this.  My first guess is something like

$(x>2~or~x=2)=x \ge 2$

But that's kind of ugly.
Does anyone know what the standard notation for this is?

Comment: It's true by definition. I would simply write ($x>2$ or $x=2$) $\Leftrightarrow x\ge 2$.

Comment: This one is [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4237608/505767)

Comment: I would write $x>2 \vee x=2 \Leftrightarrow x\geq 2$

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

$\{x > 2\} \; \cup \; \{x=2\} = \{x \geq 2\}$

Writing the overall result as a union of 2 sets.

You can also use the logical OR symbol $\lor$.

To an extent, it depends on the math background of your audience, since there are multiple correct notations.